# SQL запрос с JOIN (задача)

Tags: sql, join

есть задача:

> У отца всегда только один сын. Сыновья в свою очередь также могут быть отцами.  Запросы:
> (1) получить пользователя вместе с его отцом и сыном,
> (2) получить дедушку пользователя,
> (3) получить прадедушку пользователя.

Все данные находятся в одной таблице `users: id, name, sons_id`
По одному запросу у меня получается доставать отца и сына, вмести почему-то начинает слетать нумерация и все путаются, деда и прадеда достать вообще не получается.

Помогите разобраться как доставать это все из одной таблицы, совмещать несколько и доставать из них запросы умею, задача именно в том что бы достать все из одной таблицы.

Вот так выглядит мой запрос:

```
SELECT sons.name as son, father.name as father 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN users as sons ON users.son_id = sons.id 
INNER JOIN users as father ON father.son_id = users.id
```

но я получаю неправильный результат, ячейки соединяются не с теми id с которыми было задумано, из чего вывод что я делаю что-то не так, понять что не так сам я не смог.
[image: Вот так выглядит таблица]

[image: результат]

Comment: Вы можете делать `join` таблицы самой с собой. Все точно так же, как и с другими таблицам. В зависимости от СУБД существуют еще рекурсивные запросы

Comment: вот так выглядит мой запрос :
SELECT sons.name as son, father.name as father
 FROM users
 INNER JOIN users as sons ON users.son_id = sons.id
 INNER JOIN users as father ON father.son_id = users.id
но я получаю неправильный результат, ячейски соеденяються не с теми id с которыми было задумано, из чего вывод что я делаю что-то не так, понять что не так сам я не смог, если есть идеи - буду рад.

Comment: Добавил изображение таблицы в вопрос, в том то и задача, если я правильно ее понимаю то нужно каждый раз обращаться к таблице называя ее псевдонимом и отсеивать ненужное, и дальше использовать уже отсеянную таблицу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что очевидно бросается в глаза — запрос будет возвращать только тех пользователей, у которых есть и отец, и сын, то есть наверное где-то треть таблицы.

Дело во *внутреннем соединении* таблиц, то есть в `INNER JOIN`. Если для соединения нет подходящей пары, скажем, `users.son_id` и `sons.id`, то пользователь не попадёт в результат.

Можно использовать *внешние соединения*, в которых, даже если нет пары, вместо имени сына или отца SQL сервер вернёт `NULL`. Внешние соединения, в отличие от внутренних, асимметричны — одна из двух таблиц будет показана полностью, а вторая будет к ней присоединяться.

Запрос с левым внешним соединением вернёт имена всех пользователей, но если у них не будет отца или сына, мы увидим в этом месте `NULL`.

```sql
         SELECT users.name AS userName, sons.name AS sonName, fathes.name AS fatherName
           FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS sons ON users.son_id = sons.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS fathers ON fathers.son_id = users.id
```

Вместо `LEFT OUTER JOIN` можно писать просто `LEFT JOIN`.

Дедушка получается двойным соединением.

```sql
SELECT users.name AS userName, grandfathers.name AS grandfatherName
  FROM users
  JOIN users AS fathers ON fathers.son_id = users.id
  JOIN users AS grandfaghers ON grandfathers.son_id = fathers.id
```

Здесь `JOIN` означает `INNER JOIN`. Так мы получим всем пользователей, у которых точно есть дедушка в таблице. Заменив `JOIN` на `LEFT JOIN`, мы получим всех пользователей в таблице, с именами дедушек, если они есть, и `NULL`, если их нет.

Прадедушка получается тройным соединением.

```sql
SELECT users.name AS userName, grandgrandfathers.name AS grandgrandfatherName
  FROM users
  JOIN users AS fathers ON fathers.son_id = users.id
  JOIN users AS grandfaghers ON grandfathers.son_id = fathers.id
  JOIN users AS grandgrandfaghers ON gramdgrandfathers.son_id = grandfathers.id
```

Comment: правльно ли я понял, в таблице father которую мы используем уже для дедушки хранится измененная после запроса информация (отец-сын) ?

Comment: логику присойденения я понял, но у меня получаються смешанные результаты, имена не в свои поля попадают, скрин прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: Если я уберу AS в JOIN то как я получу результат? я обращаюсь к одной и той же таблице.
Убрал в выборке, в итоге оно отображает только юзера и id сына, последнего пользователя выводит как NULL

Comment: @aleksandr_abc, почему не в свои? Судя по таблице и по результату, запрос возвращает ровно то, что вы хотите. Самый старший Вася, потом Петя, потом Ваня, потом Коля. У Пети сын Ваня и отец Вася, у Вани сын Коля и отец Петя, у Коли нет сына (он самый младший) и отец Ваня, наконец, у Васи нет отца (он старший) и сын Петя. Всё правильно.

Comment: Точно, как-то глаз замылился за время работы, спасибо, все понял, все увидел)

Comment: А вот по поводу ответа Дмитрия, не могли бы вы дать пример подобного решения задачи (где нужно достать деда) без AS, а то я не совсем понимаю как это будет работать, если я правильно понимаю когда мы соединяем таблицу через JOIN и даем ей новое имя через AS мы создаем новую таблицу с результатами ее выборки, с которой в последствии и работаем. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @aleksandr_abc Деда я в ответе написал, должно работать. У меня там ключевое слово `AS` есть. По поводу ответа Дмитрия лучше уточнять у Дмитрия. :)

Comment: Да, Марк, все работает, спасибо вам большое!